# Full URLs to images are understood as webpages redirecting to same page after making clean urls in .HTACCESS

Tags: javascript, image, apache, .htaccess, lightbox

I want to create clean links for a website I am working on and images are not showing correctly. I used the `.htaccess` file to rewrite the URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule home index.html
RewriteRule braids braids.html
```

I knew there could be some path issues using it that way which is why I used the full URL for images in `braids.html`. However they still do not work. Image does not show. When I tried to enter image link it redirects me to the same page I was before `braids.html`.

Could you please help me with solution?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I've checked the chrome console to look for possible cause. It shows following errors for each image that is not showing:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://example.com/images/braids/braids1.jpg with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

EDIT2: I forgot to mention that I am using javascript lightbox to display images. Other images outside of  display as intended.

`<a href="https://example.com/img/braids/braids (4).jpg"  data-lightbox="braids"><img class="imggal" src="https://example.com/img/braids/braids (4).jpg"/></a>`

Comment: Your RewriteRule pattern `braids` matches `img/braids/braids (4).jpg` as well - because `braids` just has to occur _anywhere_ in the requested URL path. You want to anchor your pattern at the beginning, and possibly also at the end – `^braids$`. Go read up on the basics of regex pattern matching a bit.

Comment: It's working now! Thank you very much!